# Javascript inner method do not recognise all arguments

Tags: javascript

My `groupId` argument is not recognized on `updateDoc` function while other parameters are recognized. `groupId` is only recognized on `updateUserGroups` level.

```
async function updateUserGroups(userId, groupId, groupData) {
    const userDoc = await getDocById('users', userId)
    if (userDoc.data()['user_groups'] === undefined) {
        updateDoc('users', userId, {
            'user_groups': { groupId: groupData['creation_time'] }
        })
    }
}
```

Why is that?

Comment: You're using `groupId` as a literal key, not a variable. You need to write `{[groupId]: groupData['creation_time']}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you meant to do:

```
'user_groups': { [groupId]: groupData['creation_time'] }
```

Instead of:

```
'user_groups': { groupId: groupData['creation_time'] }
```

Because if you don't put the `[]`, the name of the property (the key) will just be `groupId`, it's name (the key) will not be equal to what is stored in `groupId`